# MacでPythonの環境構築時、jupyter notebookのインストールでエラーが出てしまいます

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pip

Hreomebw,pyenv,Pythonインストール済み
その後、`pip install jupyter` をターミナルで実行したところ以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyzmq
Failed to build pyzmq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

pipのwheelが問題みたいなので `pip install wheel` は試したのですが大丈夫でした。
Python 3.12.0a0でMACです。
この後何をすれば jupyterをinstallできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 3.12.0a0でMACです。
```

3.9、3.10など、動作実績のある安定したバージョンを使ってみてください。

Comment: できました！先輩ありがとうございます！